# How or where can I obtain an original, official copy of the ISO 8583 standard: the 1987 version?

Tags: iso8583

ISO 8583 was originally published in 1987. A revised version was published in 1993 and another in 2003.

The ISO do not sell it any more. They say that withdrawn standards are available from their office, and their office has confirmed that they can sell me a copy of the 1993 version, but (stunningly) they apparently don't even have a PDF file of the original 1987 version.]

I have googled extensively, and found multiple third-party versions of the standard (from Visa/Mastercard/JPOS/NIBSS/etc.) but they all vary to a greater or lesser degree and I particularly want a copy of the standard in its original 33 pages.

Comment: I don't believe you legally can. That said, I never had it, and it wasn't a problem for the decades I've worked in financial transactions. Software like jPOS make it really to use the standards, while in general what you need is the specific document from the interface you are connecting to. If you need to specify your own interface spec, that's other thing, but you can use

Comment: Cheers Andres. You are right: I don't NEED it. It's a bit anal of me I suppose but, having been in the the industry for only a year, and having seen multiple different versions of the spec, it would help me get my head around things to see what it looked like in the beginning.